# How would I keep all items inside an array function? Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How would I put all the numbers inputted in the function `getNum()`, into the `finalArr` `Array`, without moving `var finalArr = [];` outside the function it is in? At the moment, no matter how many cycles I run the script, it only displays the very last number I entered.

```
function getNum () {

     do {    
         number = Number(prompt("Enter a number:"));
     }
     while (number < 0);

     return number;

}

function finalArray () {

    var finalArr = [];
    finalArr.unshift(number);
    alert(finalArr);

    return;
}

do {
     getNum();
     finalArray();
     var no = prompt("Enter n to stop");
}
while (no != "n");
```

Comment: What do you want to do with your code?
Could you explain your purpose?

Comment: I want it to save all the "numbers" inputted, into an array, then sort them. However, I can't put any variable outside a function.

Comment: *"without moving `var finalArr = [];`*: why!? That really kills it, and makes you lose whatever you already had collected in that array.

Comment: It's for an assignment.

Comment: Are you allowed to keep it in another function?

Comment: Yes, as long as it isn't outside the any function.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call your finalArry() method with in your getNum() method and remove calling it from do loop.

Comment: I attempted this, however it's giving me the same results as before.

Comment: With in your finalArray() method convert this line.    FinalArr.unshift(num) to this line.    finalArr.push(num)

Comment: This doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a recursive function instead of a while loop?

Look at the next code:

```js
var array = [];

function getNum () {

  var no = prompt("Enter n to stop");

  if (no === "n") {

    console.log("the final array is");
    console.log(array);

  } else {

    array.push(no);

    getNum();

  }

}

getNum();
```

**EDIT:** I don't understand why you want to declare the `Array` inside the function, every variable declared inside a function lives just in that scope. But if it is necessary for you, you could pass the `Array` value to the function, declare the `Array` inside the function getting the value that you have passed and return the resulting `Array`, it is a bit tricky but it works:

```js
var array;

function finalArray(array, number) {

  var finalArr = array || [];

  finalArr.push(number);

  return finalArr;
}

function getNum() {

  var no = prompt("Enter a number. Enter n to stop");

  if (no === "n") {

    console.log("the final array is");
    console.log(array);

  } else {

    array = finalArray(array, +no);

    getNum();

  }

}

getNum();
```

Comment: This would work, ideally, but I need to keep the variable within the function.

Comment: Look at my last edit. If you can't do this you need to explain what do you want to do and why these solutions don't work for you.